# What is the default swap size?

Tags: default, swap, ubiquity

How does the installer calculate what size of swap partition to create? Presumably it's based on installed RAM size, but does that depend on how much RAM?

Comment: There's no Default value  it depends on how much RAM you have.

Comment: Well yes, but I was looking for a little more detail than "it depends". Is it always a set multiple of RAM size, or does it depend on how much RAM there is? For example, large RAM sizes would never need more than enough to enable hibernation, but very small RAM sizes could benefit from a swap considerably bigger than 1:1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there is no `dphys-swapfile` program on a default Ubuntu installation CD and it is not used to calculate the *swap* size.

What happens is that the `ubiquity` installer uses the `partman-auto` scripts and configuration files (called **recipes**) to determine the sizes of all partitions. It works like this:

- Partman finds the right recipe file according to the type of the computer and the option the user has chosen.
- There it finds the minimum and maximum size of the partition and its priority. For *swap* it can be 96 (min - in MB) 512 (priority) 300% (max).
- Then it gets the RAM size (via `/proc/meminfo`).
- It uses its own algorithm to calculate the sizes.

**Details:**

A **recipe** file can look like this:

```
1 1 1 free
    $iflabel{ gpt }
    method{ biosgrub } .

500 10000 -1 $default_filesystem
    $lvmok{ }
    method{ format }
    format{ }
    mountpoint{ / } .

96 512 300% linux-swap
    $lvmok{ }
    method{ swap }
    format{ } .
```

The algorithm to calculate the sizes:

```
for(i=1;i<=N;i++) {
   factor[i] = priority[i] - min[i];
}
ready = FALSE;
while (! ready) {
   minsum = min[1] + min[2] + ... + min[N];
   factsum = factor[1] + factor[2] + ... + factor[N];
   ready = TRUE;
   for(i=1;i<=N;i++) {
      x = min[i] + (free_space - minsum) * factor[i] / factsum;
      if (x > max[i])
         x = max[i];
      if (x != min[i]) {
         ready = FALSE;
         min[i] = x;
      }
   }
}
```

For more see:

- [partman-auto-recipe.txt](http://web.archive.org/web/20130405011011/http://debian.ues.edu.sv/compartidos/neozerosv/ciberues/partman-auto-recipe.txt)<sup>Way Back Machine</sup>
- <s>http://dev.blankonlinux.or.id/browser/pattimura/ubiquity/d-i/source/partman-auto/lib/recipes.sh?rev=pattimura%2Cubiquity%2C261</s> <sup>DEAD LINK</sup>

Comment: Interesting debate: a better reference than a strange debian website?

Comment: Well I found that too when I searched for it but the package has a "Warning: This package is intended for the use in building debian-installer images only. Do not install it on a normal Ubuntu system.". I assumed this was not used so I searched on and found the code for dphys-swapfile >:-D Hmm interesting indeed.

Comment: @enzotib: why strange?

Comment: @arrange: strange because not an official ubuntu site, and also as a debian site do not seems an official one.

Comment: I found 2 more methods on calculating swap size D: This method uses grep ^Mem: /proc/meminfo or if that is 0 grep ^MemTotal: /proc/meminfo and then multiplies by 2 (default) or 3 (most are set to 300%) with a minimum per architecture. A mipsel-sb1-bcm91250a uses a fixed 512. i386-efi uses 200%.

Comment: @enzotib: I can't find a better reference than the source code and the original doc files, be it on a "strange website", sorry :)

Comment: @arrange: i give a look at the installed packages and at the installer in a virtual machine: no `dphys-swapfile`, but found references to swap and recipes in various `partman` files, so i tend to give you credit now, even if cannot understand the whole mechanism behind. You get an upvote.

Answer (score 20):

This is going to be rather technical but was fun to find out so here goes...

- I found a package `dphys-swapfile` and here is the [Source code](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/dphys-swapfile.8.html). Option `setup` is used to set it up:

```
setup - tells dphys-swapfile  to compute the optimal swap file size and
(re-)generate an fitting swap file. Default it 2 times RAM size.
This  can  be called at boot time, so the file allways stays the
right size for current RAM, or run by hand whenever RAM size has
changed.
```

- Inside `dphys-swapfile` is a setting `conf_swapsize` for a pre-defined size (in Natty this is empty):

```
size we want to force it to be, default (empty) gives 2*RAM
CONF_SWAPSIZE=
```

and a setting for a `swapfactor`...

```
this is what we want, 2 times RAM size
SWAPFACTOR=2
```

- The actual size is calculated a bit further on:

  ```
  if [ "${CONF_SWAPSIZE}" = "" ] ; then
      # compute automatic optimal size
      echo -n "computing size, "
      # this seems to be the nearest to physical RAM size, lacks about 60k
      KCORESIZE="`ls -l /proc/kcore | awk '{ print $5 }'`"
      # make MBytes which rounded down will be exactly 1 too few, so add 1
      MEMSIZE="`expr "${KCORESIZE}" / 1048576 + 1`"
      # default, without config file overwriding, swap=2*RAM
      CONF_SWAPSIZE="`expr "${MEMSIZE}" '*' "${SWAPFACTOR}"`"
    fi
  ```

As you can see the way they calculate it in this package depends on the size of `/proc/kcore`, then gets divided by 1048576, +1 to round it up and then gets multiplied by swapfactor. From my machine:

[image]

So the default for this system would be 1065349120 / 1048576 = 1015+1 = 1016 * 2 = 2032 MBytes.

Comment: Pls consider to update the 'Source code' link, it does not exist anymore.