# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS swap partition on ACER Aspire 5720

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, acer, swap

I have an ACER Inspire 5720 laptop PC (32bits) and will install Ubuntu14.04 LTS on it.

The hard drive has a 160 GB capacity with 2 GB Ram memory. I should like to know how much space I have to reserve for swap and system to keep my PC quick and with enough memory to install a  lot of programs.

Comment: Recommended and [default `/swap` size](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50308/what-is-the-default-swap-size) is twice the RAM (assuming you have 2 GB then it would be 4 GB). I'd just let the installer take care of it (see [answer to this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)). For a manual partitioning (recommended for advanced users) see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation.

Comment: Usually people recommend a swap size of about 1-2x the RAM size. But depending on what you are going to do, also less or more might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

0 bytes is the perfect swap size - that is do not create a swap partition and do not bother with swap at all. If you ever find this is indeed a problem (I never have), then create a swap file - with a swap file it is easy to experiment with the right size (half of your RAM size to start with and then up to 2 times that).

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me if the first option, installing Ubuntu (automatic install without any changes) should be the best way, or do they make automaticly a swap?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case.

1. If you're a very **light user** that only ever had one tab open in FireFox (forget about chromium) only uses two applications at a time (like Firefox and Thunderbirdand that doesn't need hibernation: No swap necessary.
2. **medium user**: With only 2GB of RAM, I would put in a 4GB `swap` so you can have multiple tabs open (and individual tabs will be swapped out) and 3-6 applications open.  You will also be able to use hibernation.
3. **Heavy user**: buy more RAM!  **;-)**

***Some free tips:***

I wouldn't install Ubuntu, but Xubuntu.  Read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives) for more details.

I would take [system back-ups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) into account. (as you will be re-installing, just go for User type 4)